# Creating a C++ Project Template Wizard in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, project, wizard

Having discovered that the "Export Template" option in Visual Studio 2015 is (annoyingly) disabled for C++ projects, I searched around and found a few sources indicating that creating a Custom Wizard to generate customised C++ projects is the only available option.

I've scanned through the MSDN documentation on the subject, whilst loosely following this [Code Project tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13745/How-to-create-a-custom-project-template-using-Visu).

My issue is that the above tutorial seems to be largely incomprehensive. In the "Project Settings" segment, the author demonstrates how to modify the `AddConfig()` function to match his/her own preferences, but does not identify any other variables that can modified or the values that they can be set to. (The Code Project tutorial also briefly mentions, directly after the `AddConfig()` code, some javascript that should be used, but does not specify where, specifically, it should be typed.)

As far as I can tell, MSDN also does not provide a comprehensive list of compiler options that can be accessed by Custom Wizards through their (C#??) code. (I have never used C# before, but I'd imagine that it looks something like the code I am met with whilst creating a Wizard.)

All I am attempting to do is to automate some basic tasks that I always carry out when creating a new C++ solution:

1. Create an empty project.
2. Change the Output Directory to: `$(ProjectDir)Output\$(PlatformTarget) $(Configuration)\`
3. Change the Intermediate Directory to: `$(ProjectDir)Files\`
4. Change the Debugging Working Directory to: `$(OutputPath)`
5. Change the Character Set to UNICODE
6. Create a `main.cpp` file (containing an absolutely bare minimum console/WinAPI skeleton. (It would be great if this choice is presented to the user in the Wizard itself.))
7. Enable/disable the console (for console/WinAPI applications respectively.)
8. Set the Configuration to Release (x64)

The only relevant configuration instructions I noted in the Code Project tutorial is the character set options. This has been bugging me for such a long time now, so any help would be **hugely** appreciated!

Comment: Last time I checked there is a "Export Template" for C++ projects, I recently made one

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! It turns out there was an update to Visual Studio that I had not yet applied that enabled the export of C++ templates. Cheers for the pointer! I'm still figuring out how Stack Overflow works, but I shall mark that as the accepted answer once I figure out how. Thank you.

Comment: This is a comment, you can't accept a comment as an answer :)

Comment: Cheers, I realised not long after I commented. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know this is outdated but for people searching for this: meanwhile they got a better documentation about the [Visual Studio SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates) and especially how to create a Wizard where you can define template parameters, which are then applied to your template project.